# How to get 100% height on floated neighboring divs?

Tags: html, css

```
​<div id='container'>
    <div class='left'></div>
    <div class='right'></div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Given the simple markup above, which can be seen in action [**here at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6XagR/), how do you get the floated `right` div to take up the remaining height of its parent container that doesn't have an explicit height? The parent container's final height is determined by the floated `left` div.

Typically, I solve this issue through Javascript, and fix the heights after the page has loaded. But, there must be an alternative, standard, and optimal method of how this is handled.

I think this is just an inherent issue of structuring a layout this way, so what is the alternative beyond using a `<table>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't be done without explicit height on the parent using floats.

You can however use `display: table-;` and `table-cell` which mimics the behavior of tables without actually using them:

```
#container { 
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    display: table;
}
.left {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
.right {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

This way you don't need the clearing element and the two divs will always take up 100% of the height, as long as it's declared.

http://jsfiddle.net/6XagR/4/
    ​

Comment: Excellent, now is this a standard way of handling columns in a layout that vary in height? Or is there a design paradigm I'm overlooking with columns?

Comment: There aren't really any "standard ways" of doing things like this, but this is pretty robust, so long as you don't expect IE7< support. There is of course the CSS3 columns, but it's not as of yet widely supported.

Comment: That is good and neat solution, if you don't need margins between these "pseudo-cells". Otherwise, you have to try something else. There are few other approaches for this.

Comment: Yes, good point. This method doesn't allow margins between the cells themselves, you can of course fake it with a "margin element" (an element that is as wide as your padding" but then you're getting into unnecessary markup.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed to know, and I was looking for this alternative.